# Changing frame of a UIView is not working fine

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, frame

I have a small problem which I am not able to get why this is happening.

I have a customised NavigationView. My requirement is to change the frame of this NavigationView  when tap on google map. I mean I have to show and hide (toggle) the frame with animation.

Below is my code :-

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    if false == boolTapOnNavigationView {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

               self.viewNavigation.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60)
               //self.viewNavigation.isHidden = true
        })
        boolTapOnNavigationView = true
    }

    else {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            //self.viewNavigation.isHidden = false
            self.viewNavigation.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60)
        })
        boolTapOnNavigationView = false
    }
}
```

In my code you can see I have a flag called 'boolTapOnNavigationView'.

That code is working fine if I will tap on google map but when I will tap on any other button in same ViewController then frame of that NavigationView is reflecting automatically.

Comment: Its not clear what is your problem actually! did you have added delegate to the view controller `mapView.delegate = self`? or can you please say, where you facing complexity?

Comment: Yes mapView.delegate = self added.
My problem is I have a customise navigation view on top of google map.
I want to change the frame while tap on google map.
Thanks

Comment: just try changing mapview fram and check if issue exists?

Comment: Yes I changed mapView frame , Same issue for mapview also.

Comment: I think you are missing something, but not with your given snippet. Take a look at here: https://github.com/GolapHasan/Google-Map-Demo

Comment: I tried this also. But why taping on other button frame is getting changed?

Answer (score 0):

You should change center not frame

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        if false == boolTapOnNavigationView {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

                   self.viewNavigation.centre.y = self.viewNavigation.centre.y - 100
                   //self.viewNavigation.isHidden = true
            })
            boolTapOnNavigationView = true
        }

        else {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                //self.viewNavigation.isHidden = false
                self.viewNavigation.centre.y = self.viewNavigation.centre.y + 20
            })
            boolTapOnNavigationView = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is fine. But Same problem Like If will tap any other button then frame is reflecting automatically.

Comment: In Image you can see a green button. First when I tap on map view then frame its working fine but when I tap on green button that frame is coming down. There is no action for frame.

Comment: your button passing tap to mapview

Comment: Nothing in button tap action.